# execute a curl command using apache http client

Tags: java, json, curl

I am executing a curl command

curl -X POST -v -k --user admin:pass123 --data "{SOME JSON DATA}" --header "Content-Type:application/json" https://testhost.com:443/test/endpoint

And this success with the curl.

But when I try to execute it with java code it fails as giving

Authentication failed for this resource.","code":"401"

here is my java code

```
    String content = "SOME JSON DATA";
    String user = "admin:pass123";
    String endpoint = "https://testhost.com:443/test/endpoint"; 

    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(endpoint);
    postRequest.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");

    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", user));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", content));

    try {
        postRequest.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
       // postRequest.setEntity(new StringEntity(content));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(postRequest);
        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        String line = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line);
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Can someone explain me whats is the reason for this error?

Comment: You can't just translate the curl-specific parameters like that and hope it works. HTTP uses a standardized way of authentication (most likely basic in  your case) so google around for that.

Comment: "user" should be passed as a header called "Authorization" and be Base64 encoded. You need to perform the following steps: Build a string of the form username:password, Base64 encode the string, then supply an "Authorization" header with content "Basic " followed by the encoded string, (e.g. "Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=")
Referenced from  https://developer.atlassian.com/stash/docs/latest/how-tos/example-basic-authentication.html